# How to enable $locationProvider.html5Mode for modern browser only?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router, internet-explorer-9, html5-history

I'm working on the web app using ASP.Net 5 and AngularJS. I have completed it and it works great, but when it was released live I found out it doesn't work in IE9 which is a big part in our company.

I'm using ui-router and I was fallowing Stephen Walter tutorial for the client routing: [link here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/16/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-3-adding-client-routing)

Unfortunately his method to remove # from the URL works only for IE10+, because IE9 do not support HTML5 History API.

Spend few days on this one already and cannot find what step I have to keep using clean url for the modern browsers but not IE9?

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!--Redirect selected traffic to index -->
        <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My app.js:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            templateUrl: '/templates/appcontainer.html',
            controller: 'indexController'
        })
        .state('app.stateIndex', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
            controller: 'dashListController'
        })
        .state('app.stateList', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
            controller: 'dashListController'
        })
        .state('app.stateDashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard/:id',
            templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
});
```

When I launch it in IE9, a blank page is displayed and when I check the source code index.html is loaded, but the content of `<ui-view class="main-view"></ui-view>` is not.

Answer (score 0):

> what step I have to keep using clean url for the modern browsers but not IE9?

Use a conditional statement in the config block to exclude IE9 from html5Mode via feature detection. For example:

```
if(!!$window.innerWidth && !$window.matchMedia)
  {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: false, requireBase: false});
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix("search");
  }
else
  {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
  }
```

**References**

- [angular.js issue 10002: ng-controller on `<html>` tag fails on IE9](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10002)